# Using svn delete in a URL with space character

Tags: svn

I' trying to remove a file in a remote repository with a space character.

```
svn delete -m "Deleting file" "https://svn.xyz.edu/applications/workshop/H Y P W 2011_2.pdf"
```

I get the error

```
svn: URL 'https://svn.xyz.edu/applications/workshop/H%2520Y%2520P%2520W%25202011_2.pdf' does not exist
```

How to resolve this problem and delete the file?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason it appears to be trying to double URI encode the URL. It changes the space to `%20`, then changes the `%` to its encoded value `%25`, giving you `%2520`.

Try putting the `%20` in there yourself:

```
svn delete -m "Deleting file" "https://svn.xyz.edu/applications/workshop/H%20Y%20P%20W%202011_2.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, please use Delete command in local, then commit to SVN. I tried in my side, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a really old question but this bit me today, so here's the answer.

You may be tripping over [bug #3636](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3636) in subversion, which was fixed in [subversion 1.6.12](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.12/CHANGES)

So upgrade subversion to 6.1.12 or better if you're on an old version.

Can't upgrade for some reason ?  All is not lost. You can rename the directory so it has no spaces and then delete that directory

```
svn mv "https://svn.xyz.edu/url with spaces" https://svn.xyz.edu/urlwithoutspaces -m "subversion issue #3636"

svn delete https://svn.xyz.edu/urlwithoutspaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
svn delete -m "Deleting file" "https://svn.xyz.edu/applications/workshop/H%20Y%20P%20W%202011_2.pdf"
```

which will URL encode the spaces properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually inserting the encoded space character:

```
H+Y+P+W+2011_2.pdf
```

or

```
H%20Y%20P%20W%202011_2.pdf
```

Comment: SVN 1.1+ should allow spaces, and versions prior required you to escape spaces manually with %20 - see http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.1.html

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check out the repo and commit the delete?